# Calling javascript in my android webview app

Tags: javascript, php, android, html, css

I've got a mobile site that use a .JS file to adapt image, font etc. 
On browser it works well, but when I use my app I need to reload a page 3 times to see my site correctly. I don't understand the reason.
I think that javascript doesn't work well in my app.
this is my Mainactivity.js

```
import android.app.Activity; 
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseInstallation;
import com.parse.PushService;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView mWebView;

     /**
      * Dichiariamo l'attributo di classe url in cui 
      * salviamo l'indirizzo web che aprirà la webview
      */
    private String url = "http://www.bestparty.altervista.org/Mobile";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //carichiamo la webview dentro il layout specificato

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);       
        //carichiamo finalmete la url
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        mWebView.loadUrl(url);

    }


}
```

this is my func.js (in my site)

```
    $(document).ready( function(){
 if ($(window).width() > 1001 && $(window).width() < 10000 ) 
    { 
     $("#menubar").css("font-size", ((($(window).height()*8)/100)));
     $(".fotoevento").css("height", ((($(window).height()*45)/100)));
     $(".fotoevento").css("width", ((($(window).height()*100)/100)));
      $(".pub").css("margin-left", ((($(window).height()*13)/100)));
      $(".testievento").css("font-size", ((($(window).width()*3)/100)));
      $("#footer").css("font-size", ((($(window).width()*1)/100)));


              //MOBILE
     $(".logonavig").css("height", ((($(window).height()*3)/100)));
     $(".logonavig").css("width", ((($(window).width()*19)/100)));

     }



 else if ($(window).width() < 1000) 
    { 
     $("#menubar").css("font-size", ((($(window).height()*3)/100)));
     $(".fotoevento").css("height", ((($(window).height()*35)/100)));
     $(".fotoevento").css("width", ((($(window).width()*90)/100)));
      $(".pub").css("margin-left", ((($(window).height()*13)/100)));
      $(".testievento").css("font-size", ((($(window).width()*5)/100)));
      $(".imamgineeventocompleta").css("margin-top", ((($(window).height()*9)/100)));
      $("#footer").css("font-size", ((($(window).width()*2.4)/100)));


      //MOBILE
     $(".logonavig").css("height", ((($(window).height()*3)/100)));
     $(".logonavig").css("width", ((($(window).width()*47)/100)));


     }

  else { 
          $("#menubar").css("font-size", ((($(window).height()*3)/100)));
          $(".fotoevento").css("height", ((($(window).height()*60)/100)));
          $(".fotoevento").css("width", ((($(window).height()*110)/100)));
          $(".pub").css("margin-left", ((($(window).height()*60)/100)));
              $(".testievento").css("font-size", ((($(window).width()*5)/100)));

              //MOBILE
     $(".logonavig").css("height", ((($(window).height()*3)/100)));
     $(".logonavig").css("width", ((($(window).width()*35)/100)));
        }



})
```

Comment: Hi @Andrea. Put an `alert()` in your website. The android app shows the `alert()` always or not?